# Why doesn't my listener work when I put it in a Wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some very simple code below that listens for an event (a click on an anchor tag). It works fine if I create a standalone html file. But if I create a file for just the script, register and enqueue it and then add that anchor tag to a Wordpress page, nothing happens when I click it. I can see in the console that the script file was loaded. I get no error when I click the link but neither do I get the results from the script. Do I have my anchor tag written correctly? Where is my error?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="javascript:{}" class="citation">Click here</a>

    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j( ".citation" ).click(function ( )
      {
        event.preventDefault();

// do stuff

      }); 
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although you claim the click handler does seem to run, you better wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: `event` is undefined , so pass it as parameter in callback function `$j( ".citation" ).click(function ( event )`

Comment: You have jquery conflict I guess, open up Browser console and see if you have any errors there.

Comment: You might also want to make sure you're passing the `event` parameter to the function, i.e. `$j('.citation').click(function(event)){event.preventDefault();});`

Comment: Use your browser console to look at errors thrown! Those errors are important clues

Comment: As noted above, I have looked in the console and no errors were thrown.

Comment: The solution required both:
$j(document.ready(function() {...});
and 
function(event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is not defined. Make it as an argument

```
$j(".citation").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: Try remove javascript:{} from href

Comment: That causes the page to refresh when it is clicked -- and the script still doesn't run.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: See the comments for the original post.